Python CSV reader breaks if a row does not contain a field separator
I'm creating a script that works with a CSV file where I have network devices and their IP address from the same site. My goal is to collect hostnames in one list, and ip addresses in different lists depending on the network device type.
I've managed to deal with all possible erros but the ones for the use case when the CSV file is created manually (not exported from a spreadsheet as CSV file) and the user forgets to add a comma between the 2 values, or they only add the hostname or the IP address but without a comma after or before.
Right now the loop breaks when it finds a line without field separator.
Is this something easy to deal with?
For those cases the solution would be to rewrite the line (row) and add the comma, but I don't know how to do it inside the read loop of the CSV reader:

Add the comma between name and IP address
Add the comma after the hostname
Add the comma before the IP address
Add extra commas on any place

This is my CSV file that I use for testing (this one only with the missing IP address use case)
# This is the expected input
dntsw1101,10.2.3.1
# For this error I'm throwing a warning to the user
dntsw1101,
# For this error I'm throwing a warning to the user
,1.2.3.1
# For the empty line case I'm throwing a warning to the user

# CSV reader manages this error without any problem
dntsw1101,10.2.3.1,,,
!
# This is issue #1
dntsw110110.2.3.1
# This is issue #2
dntsw1101
# This is issue #3
10.2.3.1
# This is issue #4
dntsw1101,,10.2.3.1

As all the IP addresses start with 10 or 172 or 192 (private space), it would be easy to use REGEX to make the grouping in issue #1 and split the hostname and numbering from the IP address by looking for those values.

To add more details, the problem is that it is not throwing any error or exception, it only breaks. This is my current script:
# Initialize the list of network devices
switches = []
routers = []
firewalls = []
termservers = []
sitecodes = []
device_error = str('')

# Read the CSV file to populate the lists
try:
    with open(args.filename[0]) as file:
        network_devices = csv.reader(file, delimiter=",")
        for row in network_devices:
            if any(x.strip() for x in row):                # This is to handle empty rows as well as the 'except'
                # REGEX match for valid IP address that allows to filter in by only private IP addressing
                ipaddress_pattern = r'^((25[0-5]|(2[0-4]|1\d|[1-9]|)\d)\.?\b){4}$'
                valid_ip=re.match(ipaddress_pattern,row[1])
                                   
                if valid_ip:
                    # check if the site code matches the previous ones
                    x=(all(x==row[0][:5] for x in sitecodes))
                    print (str(network_devices.line_num) + ' ' + row[0])
                    if x:
                        #capture the site code
                        sitecodes.append(row[0][:5])
                    else:
                        device_error += ('\n=> Check hostname {}, line {}'.format(row[0],network_devices.line_num))

                    # capture the routers
                    x=re.search(".*(rt101|rt102)",row[0])
                    if x:
                        routers.append(row[1])
                        continue
                    
                    # capture the L2 and L3 switches
                    x=re.search(".*(rt1[1-2]|sw).*",row[0])
                    if x:
                        switches.append(row[1])
                        continue

                # Check for rows with hostname but not IP address, or invalid IP addresses not matching the REGEX expression above
                else:
                    # check if row fields are the other way round (ip,hostname)
                    if re.match(ipaddress_pattern,row[0]):
                        device_error += ('\n=> Invalid row with IP address in the first field, line {}'.format(network_devices.line_num))
                    else:
                        device_error += ('\n=> Check IP address from hostname {}, line {}'.format(row[0],network_devices.line_num))

And this is an example file, check that it breaks on line 15 when the first wrong entry appear, but does not process the last line which is correct.
esdntsw1102,10.2.3.1
esdntrt101,10.2.3.2
1.2.3.2,esdntrt102
esdntrt11,10.2.3.3

,
,,
esdntsw1101,
,10.2.3.8
esdntsw1103,10.2.3.10
esmadrt12,10.2.3.11
esdntsw1104,10.2.3.12,,
esdntsw1103,10.2.3.299
esdntsw1105,10.2.3.13
esdntrt102
esdntrt10210.2.3.14
10.2.3.15
esdntrt102,10.2.3.16


For dntsw110110.2.3.1, there's no way to even know where one value ends and the next begins. Is it dntsw1101, 10.2.3.1 or dntsw110, 110.2.3.1? Garbage in, garbage out; you can't magically handle every possible nonsense.

Or in different words, trying to implement "Do What I Mean" logic for poorly formatted input is a fool's errand. Next your idiot user will forget the last octet in the IP address or something. Figuring out how exactly to fail with a helpful error message is probably a better solution.

Yes there is a way to know where to split the string as the IP field must start with "10."
But my main question here it is, is there a way to keep the loop running until the end of the CSV file and not break where the error is?
esdntsw1101,10.2.3.1
esdntrt102          <== Now it breaks here and stop processing the file
esdntsw1105,10.2.3.13

Exactly what error/exception happens in your code? If it is something like ValueError, then you can use a try, except block to capture it and ignore the bad data.

You can capture all the invalid entries with a simple loop like the folowing:
with open('pytest.csv') as csvfile:

csvreader = csv.reader(csvfile, strict=True)
for row in csvreader:
    if len(row) != 2:
        print("Error", row, "invalid number of columns")
    else:
        if row[0] == '':
            print("Error", row, "first column is missing:")
        elif row[1] == '':
            print("Error", row, "second column is missing:")
        else:
            print(row)

Once you have separated out the valid entries you can do further checks on the tags and IP addresses as necessary.
Using your test data as above I get the following:
['esdntsw1102', '10.2.3.1']
['esdntrt101', '10.2.3.2']
['1.2.3.2', 'esdntrt102']
['esdntrt11', '10.2.3.3']
Error [] invalid number of columns
Error ['', ''] first column is missing:
Error ['', '', ''] invalid number of columns
Error ['esdntsw1101', ''] second column is missing:
Error ['', '10.2.3.8'] first column is missing:
['esdntsw1103', '10.2.3.10']
['esmadrt12', '10.2.3.11']
Error ['esdntsw1104', '10.2.3.12', '', ''] invalid number of columns
['esdntsw1103', '10.2.3.299']
['esdntsw1105', '10.2.3.13']
Error ['esdntrt102'] invalid number of columns
Error ['esdntrt10210.2.3.14'] invalid number of columns
Error ['10.2.3.15'] invalid number of columns
['esdntrt102', '10.2.3.16']


I see that replacing the " if row[0] ==''...elif row[1]=='' " clasue with "if not row[0] or not row[1]:" or "if not len(row[0]) or not len(row[1]):" is not the same, and the laters skip throwing the error.

@ZeusTM Sorry, I am not sure I understand your comment. I wrote the above code with the specific intention of keeping the error messages separate, to show exactly which item was in error.
